# Page not redirected when button is pressed

Tags: html, button

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function isVisible(){
    if(document.getElementById("nt").checked==true){
         document.getElementById("opt").style.visibility="hidden";  
    }
    else{
         document.getElementById("opt").style.visibility="visible";
    }
} 
</script>
<form align="center" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="teaching" id="t" value="teaching" onchange="isVisible()"> Teaching<br>
<input type="radio" name="teaching" id="nt" value="non-teaching" onchange="isVisible()"> Non-teaching<br>
Post Code <input type="text" name="pcode" id="pcode"><br>
Post Name <input type="text" name="pname" id="pname"><br>
<div id="opt">
Department <input type="text" name="dept" id="dept">
</div>
<input type="button" name="addv" id="addv" value="Add Vacancy"  onclick="javascript: form.action='hello.php';">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Above is addvacancy.php. On clicking button Add Vacancy, it is not directing to hello.php. It remains on the same page with values in the text boxes retained. Below is the code for hello.php.

hello.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "Hello!";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `action` to your form, and you should remove the `onclick` event from your `input` so it looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="addv" id="addv" value="Add Vacancy">
```

And add an action to your form that points to the desired URL in which your form submission will be directed to, so it looks like this:

```
<form action="hello.php" align="center" method="post">
```

That should do the trick. The action attribute tells the browser to send the form data to a form-handling PHP page.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.                                                                          <form align="center" method="post" action="hello.php">                               I removed onclick attribute from input tag and added action attribute in <form> as shown, it is still not directing to hello.php. Would really appreciate help.

Comment: Did you change your `input` type from *button* to *submit*? So it'd look like: `<input type="submit" ...`